# Pandas cast on Numpy different dtype array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm currently having an issue with the way that Pandas casts Numpy array into DataFrame.

Sample code:

```
example_array = np.array([
[1, 2, 3],
['one', 'two', 'three'],
[4.01, 5.01, 6.01],
[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])


df = pd.DataFrame(example_array, index=['int', 'string', 'float', 'nan'])

df = df.T

df.dtypes
```

output:

```
int       object
string    object
float     object
nan       object
dtype: object
```

It seems that either Numpy or Pandas does not recognise the type nor converts it properly, while looking around one of the suggestions was to specify the dtype in creating a Series, however, this does not help me as I'm working with a large Numpy array.

Example by @r-max:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': pd.Series(['1.0', '2.0', '3.0'], dtype=float), 'y': pd.Series(['1', '2', '3'], dtype=int)})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   x  y
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3

[3 rows x 2 columns]

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]: 
x    float64
y      int64
dtype: object
```

Is there a better solution to this problem? Is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any NumPy arrays in the input.

Comment: Fixed. Either from what I saw is that Pandas converts it into a Numpy array

Comment: Okay, you've got an array now, but that's an array of object dtype. You'll want to avoid building arrays like that if you want to use NumPy effectively.

Comment: Hint : if you just try printing the dataframe, you will know why everything is marked as object

Comment: As you can see from the first example, I have constructed multiple independent lists and passed them through DataFrame, however, the result is the same. That's nice to know, but I am wondering what is the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with numpy or pandas but in the way how you have used the np.array to create the example array.

When you define the numpy array, as a nested array, each sub array will be considered as a row. So when you  try to print the 'df' in the above case, it will be as

```
           0     1     2
   int     1     2     3
string     one   two   three
 float     4.01  5.01  6.01
   nan     nan   nan   nan
```

As you can see each column has a mix of int, string, float, null.
This is why when you check the datatype of the column you get it as object.

I suppose what you want is to have these values as columns.

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three'])
arr3 = np.array([4.01, 5.01, 6.01])
arr4 = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

df = pd.DataFrame({'int': arr1, 'string': arr2, 'float': arr3, 'nan': arr4})
```

Output:

```
      int   string  float   nan
  0     1   one     4.01    NaN
  1     2   two     5.01    NaN
  2     3   three   6.01    NaN

 df.dtypes

 int         int64
 string     object
 float     float64
 nan       float64

 dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the starting array dtype:

```
In [158]: example_array = np.array([
     ...: [1, 2, 3],
     ...: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
     ...: [4.01, 5.01, 6.01],
     ...: [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])
In [159]: example_array
Out[159]: 
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['one', 'two', 'three'],
       ['4.01', '5.01', '6.01'],
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan']], dtype='<U32')
```

You've lost the distinction between strings and float and integers right away.

But starting with a list:

```
In [178]: alist =[
     ...: [1, 2, 3],
     ...: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
     ...: [4.01, 5.01, 6.01],
     ...: [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]
```

and performing a "transpose" on that to make list of tuples:

```
In [179]: blist = list(zip(*alist))
In [180]: blist
Out[180]: [(1, 'one', 4.01, nan), (2, 'two', 5.01, nan), (3, 'three', 6.01, nan)]
```

We can then make a dataframe with distinct dtypes (by column):

```
In [181]: pd.DataFrame(_, columns=list('abcd'))
Out[181]: 
   a      b     c   d
0  1    one  4.01 NaN
1  2    two  5.01 NaN
2  3  three  6.01 NaN
In [182]: _.dtypes
Out[182]: 
a      int64
b     object
c    float64
d    float64
dtype: object
```

An equivalent structured array - one field per column

```
In [184]: _181.to_records()
Out[184]: 
rec.array([(0, 1, 'one', 4.01, nan), (1, 2, 'two', 5.01, nan),
           (2, 3, 'three', 6.01, nan)],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('a', '<i8'), ('b', 'O'), ('c', '<f8'), ('d', '<f8')])
```